How can I run Pandas (Python) scripts from Go?
I have several csv files that I must process using the Pandas (Python) library but I would like to be able to take advantage of Go's concurrency model to process several files concurrently/parallel. So I guess each goroutine should start a Python interpreter in order to execute Pandas code. I have the csv file loaded in my Go code, so it is not simply executing a Python script but I must pass the file to the script. Is this possible?. or which approach I should use given the context of my problem. I don't know if there is any library already created for this purpose.

I found https://github.com/tliron/py4go which embeds Python in Go, but that sounds pretty arduous. It'd probably be easier to e.g. write (parts of) the CSV you want onto a Python interpreter subprocess.

Why use Go rather than the concurrency capabilities available in Python library modules?

Because the problem is part of a larger context in which Go's concurrency features are useful. Also, in Python I have no real parallelism (unless I use multiprocessing).
